# Is it a good idea to have multiple Tomcat Instances on same machine?

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7

I googled this quite a bit before asking; I just want to know what, if anything, do I need to consider if running multiple tomcat instances on a pc or server.
Both use tomcat7, one 7.0.6x the other 7.0.84, one of the applications comes with a stand alone installer that installs its own tomcat with its own port numbers and it is easier to use the installer than it is to deploy under 7.0.84. Basically just want to know if having 2 running at the same time will cause any conflicts or performance issues. Is it a good practice to run 2 different tomcat versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running multiple JVMs will have a memory impact (because a JVM has a certain minimum size), and, because of that memory usage, a performance impact if swapping virtual memory is required.

There are advantages to running multiple JVMs on a single machine, though. Briefly:

1. If a JVM fails, only the applications hosted on that JVM are affected; other JVMs and applications continue to run.
2. Different applications may have different JVM, server (Tomcat) or library requirements; running multiple JVms may be the only way to meet those requirements.